# I need a regular expression that matches "origin-xx"

Tags: php, regex

I have some URI's that are coming in and I need to capture any ones that have "origin-xx" in the subdomain, and only in the subdomain. I want the returned match to equal whatever the wildcard ('xx') was.

Matches:

- `Origin-www.blahblah.com`

  `$match[0] = 'www'`
- `Origin-uk.blahblah.com`

  `$match[0] = 'uk'`

Not a match:

- `www.blahblah.com`
- `www.origin.blahblah.com`
- `www.blahorigin-blah.com`
- `uk.blahblah.com`

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I didn't word this very well. The match should be just the wildcard. So if the `HTTP_HOST` was `origin-uk.blahblah.com` the match would be `uk`. I've edited the above example to reflect this better.

EDIT 2: I also should have included that I am doing this is PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which flavor of regexp?
Is it in PHP?

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/^Origin\-([^\.]+)\./';
preg_match($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $pattern, $m);
print $m[1];
```

Comment: Very close, I don't want the 'origin-' or the '.' to be in the match though. My fault, I worded the question poorly.

Comment: @Ryan: $m[1] shouldn't include Origin- or the dot. I'm not by my computer now so I can't double check.

Comment: Oh I must have goofed something up. You are right this does exactly what I needed, thank you! I just want to add that I modified it using @c.anna suggestion of [Oo] to capture either "Origin" or "origin." I didn't specify that in my original question, and all of my examples were 'O' so my final pattern was:

/^[Oo]rigin\-([^\.]+)\./

Comment: $m[0] has the full string, $m[1] has the correct match. And if you throw in an "i" (without the quotes) right after the last slash you'll match lowercase origin as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(Origin-(www|uk)(\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[_\-][a-zA-Z0-9]*)*)+)+\.com)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[View on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/FgVtASTmpmbgNqdK)

This will catch both of your examples and not catch all of your "Not a match" examples. If you need something either more or less specific... or different, you'll need to clarify.

Comment: Vote up for the link to debuggex. That is the coolest tool I have never used before. Love the graphical display, it makes messy regex code easy to understand.

Comment: I like the visual representation and the explanation, but I'm not a big fan of promoting soon-to-be-paid tools here. Looks nice though!

Answer (score 2):

One regex that should work for you is `\b[oO]rigin-(\w+)\b`. Here's a RegExr link: http://regexr.com?35sq3. In this regex, group 1 contains the value you're interested. The `\b` fields are only necessary to remove matches in the middle of the string. If you know that `Origin` will be at the beginning of a string, you could replace the first `\b` with `^` and the last one with `$`

Comment: It does only happen in the subdomain and is the very first part, so ^ would work. This works for my original question but I worded it poorly. I don't want the 'origin-' to be in the match, just the 'www' or 'uk' etc. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression would work for the subdomain: `Origin-([a-z]{2}|www)`. For the complete one, it can be something like: `Origin-([a-z]{2}|www)\.blahblah\.com`

You can use the ( ) to reference the capture group.

Comment: This will not match **Origin-www.blahblah.com** as it should, stated in the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now it does.

Comment: Now it matches **Origin-wwwwww.blahblah.com** because of the `{2}` after your capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more parameters this would work
    /Origin-([a-zA-Z*?)\./

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, you want to make sure that the very beginning of the string is "origin", so start with a `^`, which means beginning of string. Then you'll match any text, up to a dot.

```
/^origin-([a-z]+)\./
```

Comment: Very close, I don't want the 'origin-' or the '.' to be in the match though. My fault, I worded the question poorly.